# How calculate diff() in condition value? Python

Tags: python

I have a pandas df, like this:

```
    ID  date        value
0   10  2022-01-01  100
1   10  2022-01-02  150
2   10  2022-01-03  0
3   10  2022-01-04  0
4   10  2022-01-05  200
5   10  2022-01-06  0
6   10  2022-01-07  150
7   10  2022-01-08  0
8   10  2022-01-09  0
9   10  2022-01-10  0
10  10  2022-01-11  0
11  10  2022-01-12  100
12  23  2022-02-01  490
13  23  2022-02-02  0
14  23  2022-02-03  350
15  23  2022-02-04  333
16  23  2022-02-05  0
17  23  2022-02-06  0
18  23  2022-02-07  0
19  23  2022-02-08  211
20  23  2022-02-09  100
```

I would like calculate the days of last value. Like the bellow example. How can I using diff() for this? And the calculus change by ID.

Output:

```
    ID  date        value  days_last_value
0   10  2022-01-01  100    0
1   10  2022-01-02  150    1
2   10  2022-01-03  0
3   10  2022-01-04  0
4   10  2022-01-05  200    3
5   10  2022-01-06  0
6   10  2022-01-07  150    2
7   10  2022-01-08  0
8   10  2022-01-09  0
9   10  2022-01-10  0
10  10  2022-01-11  0
11  10  2022-01-12  100    5
12  23  2022-02-01  490    0
13  23  2022-02-02  0
14  23  2022-02-03  350    2
15  23  2022-02-04  333    1
16  23  2022-02-05  0
17  23  2022-02-06  0
18  23  2022-02-07  0
19  23  2022-02-08  211    4
20  23  2022-02-09  100    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': 12 * [10] + 9 * [23], 
                   'value': [100, 150, 0, 0, 200, 0, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 490, 0, 350, 333, 0, 0, 0, 211, 100]})

days = df.groupby(['ID', (df['value'] != 0).cumsum()]).size().groupby('ID').shift(fill_value=0)
days.index = df.index[df['value'] != 0]
df['days_last_value'] = days
df
```

```
    ID  value  days_last_value
0   10    100              0.0
1   10    150              1.0
2   10      0              NaN
3   10      0              NaN
4   10    200              3.0
5   10      0              NaN
6   10    150              2.0
7   10      0              NaN
8   10      0              NaN
9   10      0              NaN
10  10      0              NaN
11  10    100              5.0
12  23    490              0.0
13  23      0              NaN
14  23    350              2.0
15  23    333              1.0
16  23      0              NaN
17  23      0              NaN
18  23      0              NaN
19  23    211              4.0
20  23    100              1.0
```

First, we'll have to group by 'ID'.
We also creates groups for each block of days, by creating a True/False series where value is not 0, then performing a cumulative sum. That is the part `(df['value'] != 0).cumsum()`, which results in

```
0      1
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      3
5      3
6      4
7      4
8      4
9      4
10     4
11     5
12     6
13     6
14     7
15     8
16     8
17     8
18     8
19     9
20    10
```

We can use the values in this series to also group on; combining that with the 'ID' group, you have the individual blocks of days. This is the `df.groupby(['ID', (df['value'] != 0).cumsum()])` part.

Now, for each block, we get its size, which is obviously the interval in days; which is what you want. We do need to shift one up, since we've counted the total number of days per group, and the difference would be one less; and fill with 0 at the bottom. But this shift has to be by ID group, so we first group by ID again before shifting (as we lost the grouping after doing `.size()`).

Now, this new series needs to get assigned back to the dataframe, but it's obviously shorter. Since its index it also reset, we can't easily reassign it (not with df['days_last_value'], df.loc[...] or df.iloc).

Instead, we select the index values of the original dataframe where value is not zero, and set the index of the days equal to that.
Now, it's easy step to directly assign the days to relevant column in the dataframe: Pandas will match the indices.

Comment: Its good. But I am received a Length mismatch :(

Comment: @AnaBeatriz Could you first try with purely my code, including that fake dataframe? Then we know that at least works.

Comment: Its works! I understood the logic, and even found another solution to the problem. but if I wanted to count the worthless days, how would we do it?

Comment: Are the "worthless days" the ones where "days_last_value" equals NaN?

Comment: Yes! I would like to know the days that the ID was without making transactions. I managed to do it here, but I had to create 2 new columns, I don't know if it was the best way.

Comment: Do you want to count, or know the actual IDs? Those are different things. Also, do you want the IDs (which are the same for several NaNs), or the dataframe index?